# Cannot login to MySQL in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite, pid

Here is my problem: I cannot login to MySQL since I forgot the temporary password, i.e., the one that was assigned to me when I installed MySQL (if I type `mysql` in the command line, I receive this error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mona'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I receive the same error when I try with `mysql -u root`), so I tried the following to fix it:

1. I turned off MySQL
2. Then I created a file called `restore` in which I wrote `SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');`
3. Finally, `sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/support-files/restore` which didn't work. Then I tried step 3 with this command `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` and I got this error `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).`

In order to fix the last error, I tried the followings:

1. `ps aux | grep mysql` and killed MySQL processes. Then I started MySQL server but I received the same error again.
2. I checked my.cnf file in /private/etc (everything was commented in this file except this line: `pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`, but I found there is no mysqld folder in /var/run, instead it is located in this path: `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/bin/`).
3. Now, I feel confused: why in /usr/local/, there are both `mysql` folder and `mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64`?? what is their difference then? (I know the one I installed is the latter one)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have any valuable data on the database?

Comment: @Bramastic. No, nothing

Comment: Remove MySQL completely - https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

Comment: @Bramastic I removed and reinstalled two times.. so I think I should find a real problem and solution